# Cntl + z in delphi 4.0

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Hi I am using Delphi 4 IDE.
an major irritant is that i am unable to use "undo/ cntrl+z" more than twice.

This is quite worriysome as i am wish to undo my changes as per need.

Can one do more that 2-3 times of UNDO in Delphi 4.0?

or am i missing something ?

any solutions to this?

thanks

-Vas

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using Delphi 4? This is a really old software.

Comment: Why are you complaining about possible bugs in a 10-year old IDE? Do you expect someone to fix them? Upgrade to a more recent version of the IDE if you're not happy with the ancient one you're using now.

Comment: its a legacy system , i am can't upgrade it.So does it mean that there is no way one can have more than 2 "Cntrl+z" ?

Comment: I never used D4, so I can't comment on that. But from my D5 usage I can't remember of this restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the `Group Undo` option in `Tools > Editor Options` dialog. And, increase undo buffers to a big value.

That may solve your problem.